# почему вылетает ошибка сегментации при открытии файла? Си

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Выполняю учебное задание по CS50 - сервер который отвечает на запросы браузера.
Реализую функцию indexes - ей передается путь к каталогу - что-то вроде: "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset6/public/" - моя функция принимает этот путь в качестве параметра и проверяет - если в каталоге есть файл index.php или .html - то возвращает путь с этим файлом, т.е. "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset6/public/index.html", если такого файла нет - возвращает NULL.

Сначала сделал все последовательно - все работало. Решил оптимизировать, чтобы не дублировать строки кода, завести в цикл, но теперь на 2-м проходе цикла когда добирается до открытия файла - вылетает ошибка сегментации.

```
char* indexes(const char* path)
{
    char* index_path = NULL;
    FILE* file = NULL;

    char* index[2] = {"index.html", "index.php"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (index_path != NULL)
        {
            free(index_path);
        }

        index_path = realloc(index_path, strlen(path) + strlen(index[i]) + 1);
        strcpy(index_path, path);
        strcat(index_path, index[i]);


        file = fopen(index_path, "r");
        if (file != NULL)
        {
            fclose(file);
            return index_path;
        }

    }

    free(index_path);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, второй проход.

```
if (index_path != NULL)
```

и он таки не равен!

```
{
    free(index_path);
}
```

Освободили память. `index_path` указывает на **освобожденный** блок памяти.

```
index_path = realloc(index_path, strlen(path) + strlen(index[i]) + 1);
```

И получаем неприятности - потому что функции `realloc` должен передаваться **корректный** указатель. А он у вас указывает на **освобожденный** блок памяти.

Обнулите `index_path` после освобождения...

И вообще - а почему вы используете `realloc`, а не `malloc` - раз все равно память освобождаете? Используйте просто `malloc`...

Comment: спасибо, заработало. Да, в этом случае можно malloc. Я убрал освобождение памяти и оставил realloc.

Comment: Можно и так. Главное - не использовать некорректный указатель.